# View Controller lifecycle methods are not called after init()

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, lifecycle, viewdidload

I'm facing a strange problem. I'm calling my `CommonListViewController` in the following way from my main tab bar screen:

```
self?.navigator.go(module: CommonListBuilder(mode: .vacation), mode: .push(animated: false))
```

This is my `build()` method:

```
func build() -> BaseViewController {
        CommonListViewController(interactor: CommonListInteractor(mode: mode), mode: mode)
    }
```

This method is called, then `CommonListViewController's` `init` is called:

```
init(
        interactor: CommonListInteractorProtocol,
        mode: CommonListMode
    ) {
        self.interactor = interactor
        self.mode = mode
        self.adapter = CommonListTableAdapter(mode: mode)
        self.searchAdapter = CommonListSearchAdapter()
        super.init()
        interactor.sendMetrics(event: .openScreen, params: mode.paramsForOpenScreen)
    }
```

But then nothing happens. `Loadview()`, `viewDidLoad()` (I'm using breakpoints) and other lifecycle methods are not called, so `CommonListViewController` is not opening. What can be the reason?

IMPORTANT: This happens not on the first launch, but only after switching between tabs.

Comment: What is `navigator`? What does the `go` function do? Where do you call the `build` function? There's very little clear detail in your question and I don't see a single reference to any standard navigation APIs or lifecycle methods in what you posted.

Comment: *"This happens not on the first launch, but only after switching between tabs."* -- correct. On "first launch," the controller must be loaded and `loadView()` / `viewDidLoad()` etc will be called. When switching **tabs**, the controller is already loaded, so those methods will not be called.

Comment: viewWillAppear is not called as well

Comment: Then you should check why the ViewController is not appearing.

Comment: That is my question here

Comment: @MaryLitv21 - you need to provide more detail. You mention *"switching between tabs"* but your first posted code shows *"`mode: .push(animated: false)`"* ... which would seem to indicate you have a navigation controller somewhere that is **pushing** a controller? What are you actually doing? We can't tell from the code and description you've posted so far.